# Showing that $\phi$ is a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

$G=\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a group with product $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(a+c,(-1)^cb+d)$.
Show that the image $\phi: G \to D_{10}$ with $(a,b) \mapsto s^ar^b$ is a homomorphism ($D_{10}$ is the dihedral group of order $10$).

---

I know we have to show that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$.

Let's choose some random elements in $G$: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

$\phi((a,b))\phi((c,d)) = s^{a+c}r^{-b+d}=\phi((a+c,-b+d))$

I can only make this equal $\phi((a,b)(c,d)$ if I put a restriction on $c$: $c$ can only be odd. But that doesn't prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

I'm pretty sure I have to use the fact that we're working with $D_{10}$ but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you ought to see how $r,s$ are related in $D_{10}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show that $$s^ar^bs^cr^d=s^{a+c}r^{(-1)^cb+d}$$
or - after cancelling - that
$$r^bs^c=s^{c}r^{(-1)^cb}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Jose What steps do you take for your simplification? I hope you do not secretly assume that $r$ ans $s$ commute?

Comment: Oh wow, I was using the relation $sr^i=r^{-i}s$ but I was implenting it as if $s^jr^i=r^{-i}s^j$. I see what I was doing wrong now. Thanks!